# logically equivalent $\exists x P(x)$ and $\exists x\neg P(x)$

Tags: logic

Let's say we have two sentences:

> Some cats are mammals
>
> Some cats are not mammals

Does this show that $\exists x P(x)$ and $\exists x\neg P(x)$ are logically equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the two sentences seem equivalent in natural language because of the connotations of "some". If I tell you, in ordinary conversation, "some of my socks are red", then you reasonably infer that I also have non-red socks, because otherwise I would simply have said "all of my socks are red". Similarly, if I say "some of my socks are not red" you reasonably infer that I also have red socks, since I otherwise would have said "none of my socks are red".

The mathematical translation of "some" as an existential quantifier does not have this connotation: $\exists s(R(s))$ is perfectly consistent with there being no non-red socks. Thus, because natural language is complex, the existential quantifier is not necessarily a perfect translation of the word "some".

Note that the word "some" in a *mathematical* context is usually used in a way that is more in line with the existential quantifier. If I describe a graph, for instance, and I say "we have a graph where some edges are weighted" I expect my listener to understand that we might be talking about a graph where *every* edge is weighted as a special case.

Answer (score 1):

No.

"Some cats are mammals" is true, since *all* cats are mammals.

"Some cats are not mammals" is false, for the same reason.

So the given logical statements cannot be equivalent.

Comment: I am talking more about the logic here  and not the real-life issue, another example can be: some people have money and some people do not have money

Comment: The example demonstrates that the statements are not equivalent.  If they *were* equivalent, then for any example they'd either both be true or both be false.